Vim syntax and C pointers
I followed this post on Vim highlighting and C pointers and was able to get something working. My issue is I would like to make instances bold and the actual value italicized. Something like this:

foo->bar;
foo->bar->baz;

So far the edits to my c.vim file to do so look like this:
" pointer and object highlighting
hi PTR1 cTerm=bold gui=bold

syntax match PTR1 "/\w\+\(->\)\@=/"

" stop at last instance of ->
syn region ptr1 start=/\w\+\(->\)\@=/ end=/.*\->/

How could I possibly capture the last element in the chain/value I am pointing to so I can italicize it?

Cross-posted on SO. Please don't cross-post.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

You could match the last element of the chain with the following regular expression:
\(->\)\@<=\w\+\W\@=\(->\)\@!


\(->\)\@<= must be preceded by a ->
\w\+\W\@= match the entire indentifier
\(->\)\@! must not be followed by a ->

highlight PTR2 cTerm=italic gui=italic
syntax match PTR2 /\(->\)\@<=\w\+\W\@=\(->\)\@!/

